# oci query in PHP returning array not working

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Using `print_r` bellow simply prints `Array ()`.

Why is this not working?

```
$conn = oci_connect("wwbms_admin", "wwbms_admin", "PDBQA");

$sql = "SELECT COUNTRY_ID, DESCRIPTION FROM COUNTRY";
$query_country = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

$list = array();

$result = oci_execute($query_country, OCI_DEFAULT);

while(($row = oci_fetch_assoc($query_country))) {
$items[$row['DESCRIPTION']] = $row['DESCRIPTION'];
}

print_r($list);

oci_close($conn);
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: I don't see $list ever being assigned values.  Is this a typo or is something missing from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set $list to an empty array(), then you run print_r on it. You never set it again. You're getting predictable results.

Maybe you meant to `print_r($items);`?

Comment: I apologize, I am an idiot of course yes, Thank you for making me see the obvious :)